# If I upload a picture on Facebook and customize it to, except .. Mary

Tags: facebook

If I upload a picture on Facebook and customize it to, except .. Mary. And Tom likes and comments on my picture, as Mary is a mutual friend  can Mary and other limited friends see the picture?

Answer (score 1):

If you upload a photo to Facebook, and then change the privacy on the photo to Custom and put Mary in the "Don't share this with" box, then Mary wouldn't see anything related to the photo.  She would never see the photo and she would never see when anyone likes or comments on the photo.